Chords $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ of a circle meet at the point $E$ outside the circle. Prove that
(a) $\angle A\cong\angle C$
(b) $\angle1\cong\angle 2$
(c) $\triangle ADE$ and $\triangle CBE$ are equiangular.

I tried upto some extent but did not know I to solve this problem.
I know that length of two tangents drawn from an external point to the circle are equal in length.
I joined $B$ and $D$ but I don't know how to solve this problem

Do you know the theorem about the angle subtended by an arc at the centre?

@c'estpasnormale It is not given in the statement that the two chords are congruent.
